# If $A \in SO(n)$ with eigenvector $v$, $\lambda \notin \mathbb{R}$, then $|v + \bar{v}|$ = $|i(v - \bar{v})|$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone explain why this fact, appearing in the proof of Proposition 9.19 in Kristopher Tapp's *Matrix Groups for Undergraduates*, is true?

Let $A \in SO(n)$ and let $v \in \mathbb{C}^n$ be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda \notin \mathbb{R}$.  Define $x = v + \bar{v}$ and $y = i(v - \bar{v})$.  Prove that, $|x| = |y|$.

Accept as established facts that $x$ and $y$ are nonzero and orthogonal.

Letting $\lambda = e^{i \theta}$, Tapp states that this follows from $xA = \cos(\theta)x + \sin(\theta)y$ and $yA = -\sin(\theta)x + \cos(\theta)y$.  So, presumably, he wants us to prove the result by showing that $|xA| = |yA|$, since $A$ is orthogonal.

I was hoping that there was a proof that didn't involve calculating these magnitudes separately and then equating; it gets kind of messy...  I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but, it happens..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah if you've already established that $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal, then use Pythagorean theorem:
$\|x\|^2 = \|xA\|^2 = \cos(\theta)^2 \|x\|^2 + \sin(\theta)^2 \|y\|^2 $

$\|y\|^2 = \|yA\|^2 = \sin(\theta)^2 \|x\|^2 + \cos(\theta)^2 \|y\|^2 $

Solve for $\|x\|^2$, then $\sin(\theta)^2 (\|x\|^2 - \|y\|^2) = 0$. As $\lambda$ was not real, $\sin(\theta) \neq 0$, and you have the result.

Answer (score 4):

Since $A$ is real, if $(\lambda,v)$ is an eigenpair, $(\bar{\lambda},\bar{v})$ is also an eigenpair. As $\lambda$ is nonreal, $\lambda\neq\bar{\lambda}$. Also, as $A\in SO(n)$, $A$ is a normal matrix. Hence eigenspaces for different eigenvalues are orthogonal to each other, i.e. $v\perp \bar{v}$. Therefore $\|x\|_2^2=\|y\|_2^2=2\|v\|_2^2$.

Comment: Oh I see, you are using orthogonality even more directly just computing $\langle x, x\rangle$. Bypassing the hint altogether, which is simpler. Cool.

Comment: I really like this proof too! Thank you much!